# Lwjgl is changing the color of my texture?

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, game-engine

I am trying to display a texture of a window (in 3d)
This is my code

```
try {
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res\\window.png")));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    texture.bind();
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    GL11.glVertex3f(10, 10, 0);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    GL11.glVertex3f(0, 10, 0);
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

This is the real image:

[image: window.png]

And now here's the problem: lwjgl or what ever is doing it, is totally changing the color of the texture?
this is how the image get's displayed:

[image: displayed.png]

No errors, no nothing.

Comment: That's deprecated OpenGL, you should avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color you set multiplies with the color of your image. Set your color to white before drawing the image:

```
GL11.glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```